# Why do I keep getting these errors?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

I have macbook pro 2013 with 6GB RAM and 500GB Samsung EVO SSD, running mac os catalina ?
Ikeep getting errors like this do not know why any idea what might be causing this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 6Gb of RAM? Could the memory be faulty?

Comment: You get these dialogs because these services crashed. _Why_ they crashed can only be determined by inspecting the crash reports. If they appeared recently you should be doing a [memory/hardware test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731); chances are RAM is not working correctly any more.

Comment: I see, I was doubting my ssd is having issues, but you are saying RAM could be faulty. I did not had any issues before I upgraded to Catalina though.I think the one that is compatible with my macbook is `1600 MHz PC3-12800 DDR3 SO-DIMM` !  according to this page https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-unibody-faq/macbook-pro-13-15-17-mid-2009-how-to-upgrade-ram-memory.html says maximum 16GB can also work.

Comment: Are you sure it's a 2013 MBP? What is the result of terminal command `sysctl hw.model`?

Comment: sorry Its mid 2012 model but mine is core i5.